# How to access session property ProductName in vbscript silent mode installshield express

Tags: vbscript, installshield

How can i access the session property for productname in a silent install with vbscript (installshield express 2010 or 2011).

Thank You

Comment: What's special about a silent install? Are you having problems scheduling the action?

Comment: in a silent install,  you cannot access session.properties. i need to access the product name to determine which application is being installed. different preparation steps are performed by product (in vbscripts). And yes, i am having problems with the custom action steps. especially the before system search steps. one is supposed to be for silent and one is for normal. they dont "seem" to work that way. any hep would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience you can read properties during silent installs too, using immediate custom actions. You cannot access properties using a deferred custom action. Is your custom action set as immediate?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa368268.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, they are set to execute in the express 2011 "before system search (silent mode)" and "ditto (not in silent mode)" steps. These are immediate execution steps. the productname, installdir etc values are not being returned. i am using the appropriate case for each. this install is meant to be for loud/silent installs and is a template that i use for 3 applications. This is my first attempt (for weeks now) trying to get it run correctly in silent mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the job :)

```
Dim ISProject

Set ISProject = CreateObject("IswiAuto15.ISWiProject") \*Create the object*/

ISProject.OpenProject ("C:\Path\To\ISM\Project.ism")\*Initialize it*/

ISProject.ProductName   \* Like this you get the value of the name property */

ISProject.ProductName="MyInstallShield" \* and this is how you set */

ISProject.SaveProject()
ISProject.CloseProject
```

I hope this will be helpful